# Select only the column names that contain a specific string

Tags: python, pandas

A simple example should make this obvious.  Sample data:

```
df = pd.DataFrame( np.random.randn(2,6), columns=['x','y','xy','yx','xx','yy'] )
```

Now, I just want to list the values for columns containing 'x'.  Here's a couple of ways:

```
df[[ x for x in df.columns if 'x' in x ]]
Out[53]: 
          x        xy        yx        xx
0  2.089078  1.111139 -0.218800  1.025810
1 -0.343189  0.274676 -0.342798 -0.503809

df[ df.columns[pd.Series(df.columns).str.contains('x')] ]
Out[54]: 
          x        xy        yx        xx
0  2.089078  1.111139 -0.218800  1.025810
1 -0.343189  0.274676 -0.342798 -0.503809
```

The latter approach seems promising but it's just really ugly and I haven't so far found a way to shorten it.  Something more like this would be great:

```
df[ columns_with( df, 'x' ) ]
```

and in fact I did something just like that with a function, but am wondering if there is a pandastic way to do this without a user written function or monkeypatch?

For motivation/background, this sort of thing is super useful when you have an unfamiliar dataset with lots of columns or even when you have a familiar dataset but can't remember the exact name of one variable out of hundreds.  For the situations where I need this functionality, I'll often be doing this over and over again during data exploration stages, so it's really worth it to me to have a quick and simple way to do this.

Comment: Either of your methods would be how i'd do it, otherwise I'd just put this into a function and have it return a list of columns that contain your identifier like you've already done before

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You could use [`DataFrame.filter`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.filter.html) with the `like` argument:

```
>>> df.filter(like="x")
          x        xy        yx        xx
0 -1.467867  0.766077  1.210667  1.116529
1 -0.041965  0.546325 -0.590660  1.037151
```

The `like` argument means "keep info axis where `arg in col == True`".

Answer (score 2):

@DSM's answer fully addresses this question, but the `regex` kwarg provides a comparable and more general approach than `like`.  For example, to replicate the functionality of `like`:

```
df.filter(regex='x')
```

But you can also do much more, such as:

```
df.filter(regex='^x')       # x must be the first character
df.filter(regex='X|x')      # includes upper and lower case
```